# Libgdx. Адаптивность на различных устройствах

Tags: android, libgdx, адаптивность, формулы, спрайт

Я прошерстил кучу материалов и страниц по сети. Но нигде не смог найти методы и/или объекты для отображения одних и тех же спрайтов при помощи TextureAtlas, чтобы они одинаково отображались на различных устройствах.
Есть ли такие методы/объекты? Если есть, то как их правильно настроить и использовать?
P.S. Что-то похожее смог найти: OrthographicCamera. Но опять же, как правильно её использовать для адаптивного и правильного отображения. Есть ли какие-то "формулы"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этой цели используются Viewport http://www.libgdx.ru/2014/08/viewports.html